# How to get values in a report, like in a form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

here is my situation:

I have a report that is displaying several values like the **expected** value and the **obtained** value. I would like to display an alert when the **expected** is over the **obtained**. This kind of manipulation is straightforward in a form:

```
If expectedCtrl > obtainedCtrl Then alertCtrl = "PROBLEM"
```

The problem is that in a report, its continuous aspect makes it impossible to get the expectedCtrl and obtainedCtrl values that way. Does anybody know the right way to perform this simple task ?

Thank you very much for your help, I'm really stuck on it and I don't have much time...

Comment: The continuous aspect in no way makes that impossible, BTW. The relevant events are run repeatedly for each row in the continuous form.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an unbound control and set an expression for the control data source. Something like this...

```
=iif(expectedCtrl>obtainedCtrl, "PROBLEM","")
```

Alternatively you can use the  [Conditional Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139965%28v=office.10%29.aspx) feature and define a condition to change the color, for example, of the obtainedCtrl field if it is greater than the expectedCtrl.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Comment: Yes in that case I can do it but in fact I would like to display a conditionnal picture, therefore I cannot do it in that way... I have to code it :(

Comment: How exactly to you expect alertCtrl = "PROBLEM" to set a picture? I think you need to be more specific in your question about what you want. The way it is currently worded requires reading your mind to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're right. My problem, actually, is how to get a control value on the code side in a report. It works easily in a form, but not in a report.

Comment: Can you modify your question to show your attempt at the code in the report including which event you are putting it in?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set up some code for one of the events in the Detail section of the report.  In the report's design view, right-click 'Detail', then properties, and check its events.  This will allow you to run code for each detail record that shows up on the report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include both If and Else. For a picture, I suggest you set the visible property, say:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
If expectedCtrl > obtainedCtrl Then
    Me.PicAlert.Visible = True
Else
    Me.PicAlert.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Or more simply:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.PicAlert.Visible = (expectedCtrl > obtainedCtrl)
End Sub
```